# Submit web form with Twill is not applied?

Tags: python-2.7, twill

I am trying to automate the sending of a message on a shoutbox :

http://www.i-tchat.com/shoutbox/shoutbox.php?idShoutbox=116303

When i'm using this code every thing work fine (without error) but the message is not send (submited)

```
from twill.commands import *

url='http://www.i-tchat.com/shoutbox/shoutbox.php?idShoutbox=116303'
user= 'Toto'
mess="Test message"

go(url)
formclear('1')
fv("1", "username", user)
fv("1", "message", mess)
showforms()
submit('0')
```

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
submit(url)
```

when you press the submit button you are redirected back to the same page, have you read the source code before?